# Rails Image Upload + Thumb + Delete all in one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, action, dragonfly-gem

Is it possible to render a `file_upload` tag and an `image_tag` also with an delete button using Dragonfly or another gem? This should all be rendered via the `apply_helper`, but the rest should be (I think) javascript?

Any advice is welcome!

I’m looking for something like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: what is "apply_helper" ? this is doable, but probably depends heavily on the admin system you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need something like this

[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: Thanks! This works, I only have 1 more problem: When I click the remove/garbage image_tag it opens up the file browser from the file_upload_tag why is he doing that:   http://goo.gl/lyozF Gist with the javascript code and rails code: https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/d9b67aaa6c13037a8937

Comment: This only seems to be a problem in Safari!

Comment: this may a issue of cross browser compatibility.

Comment: I will create another topic and link back here! Thanks for the help